# Prevent redirected page from loading with JS

Tags: javascript, redirect

Suppose I have these crude 3 lines of code:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.slice(0, 25) == "https://www.somepage.com") {
  location.replace(url.replace(/somepage/, "thispage");
}
```

Browser redirects, but some files from "somepage.com" (html, css files) are partialy fetched. I would like to prevent those files from being fetched completly if possible, using JS. Many thanks!
NOTE: code above has been loaded from GreaseMonkey, with "@run-at document-start" entry.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want the 'some files' to be fetched completely or not fetched at all?

Comment: not fetched at all

Comment: That's not possible with a redirect. There are probably many solutions to your problem, but you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: just a simple redirect using JS, so that nothing from redirected site gets fetched

Comment: if it is not possible with js, what are the other options?

Comment: With PHP you could load and echo the page you want to 'redirect' to, see the first example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php A similar thing could be done in JS with, for instance: http://api.jquery.com/load